# matplotlib plot negative num in diffrent color

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colors

I want use red and green to distinguish positive and negative num which will be used abs(num) in one picture. I search on web and find some method to deal with it. but the result is error. I paste the code and wish sb. to help.

"df_combine" file like this:

```
     t                      o     h        l       c    nu    octime             ocsize  cum_size
0   2017-07-02 22:01:00 1241.65 1241.85 1241.63 1241.85 0   2017-07-02 22:01:32 32  32
1   2017-07-02 22:02:00 1241.95 1241.95 1241.85 1241.95 0   2017-07-02 22:02:00 -24 12
2   2017-07-02 22:03:00 1242.05 1242.15 1242.05 1242.15 0   2017-07-02 22:03:00 -48 -36
3   2017-07-02 22:04:00 1242.25 1242.25 1242.16 1242.17 0   2017-07-02 22:04:00 -100 -136
4   2017-07-02 22:05:00 1242.16 1242.57 1241.85 1242.57 0   2017-07-02 22:05:00  200 64
```

holding_info file like this:

```
    cum_size    factor
0   32.0    True
1   12.0    True
2   -36.0   False
3   -136.0  False
4   64.0    True
```

code like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t=df_combine.iloc[:,0]
o=df_combine.iloc[:,1]
h=df_combine.iloc[:,2]
l=df_combine.iloc[:,3]
c=df_combine.iloc[:,4]

holding_octime=df_combine['t']

holding_size=df_combine['cum_size']  ##df_cumbine is a DataFrame

holding_info=pd.Series.to_frame(holding_size)
holding_info['factor']=holding_info['cum_size']>0

fig,ax1=plt.subplots()

ax1.plot_date(t,o,linestyle='--',color='b',marker='D',alpha=0.6)  ##t,o,h,l,c are pd.Series which contains time and price
ax1.plot_date(t,c,linestyle='--',color='k',marker='D',alpha=0.6)
ax1.plot_date(t,h,color='g',marker='^',alpha=0.3)
ax1.plot_date(t,l,color='r',marker='v',alpha=0.3)

ax2=ax1.twinx()   
ax2.plot_date(holding_octime,abs(holding_size),color=holding_info.factor.map({True:'r', False:'k'})) ##octime is a pd.Series which contains time

dformat=mpl.dates.DateFormatter('%Y.%m.%d %H:%M')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dformat)
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

find error like this:

```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    305                 pass
    306             else:
--> 307                 return printer(obj)
    308             # Finally look for special method names
    309             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
    238 
    239     if 'png' in formats:
--> 240         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    241     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    242         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    122 
    123     bytes_io = BytesIO()
--> 124     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    125     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    126     if fmt == 'svg':

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
   2198                     orientation=orientation,
   2199                     dryrun=True,
-> 2200                     **kwargs)
   2201                 renderer = self.figure._cachedRenderer
   2202                 bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(renderer)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
    543 
    544     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
--> 545         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    546         renderer = self.get_renderer()
    547         original_dpi = renderer.dpi

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in draw(self)
    462 
    463         try:
--> 464             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
    465         finally:
    466             RendererAgg.lock.release()

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     61     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     62         before(artist, renderer)
---> 63         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     64         after(artist, renderer)
     65 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   1142 
   1143             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
-> 1144                 renderer, self, dsu, self.suppressComposite)
   1145 
   1146             renderer.close_group('figure')

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, dsu, suppress_composite)
    137     if not_composite or not has_images:
    138         for zorder, a in dsu:
--> 139             a.draw(renderer)
    140     else:
    141         # Composite any adjacent images together

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     61     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     62         before(artist, renderer)
---> 63         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     64         after(artist, renderer)
     65 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2424             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
   2425 
-> 2426         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, dsu)
   2427 
   2428         renderer.close_group('axes')

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, dsu, suppress_composite)
    137     if not_composite or not has_images:
    138         for zorder, a in dsu:
--> 139             a.draw(renderer)
    140     else:
    141         # Composite any adjacent images together

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     61     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     62         before(artist, renderer)
---> 63         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     64         after(artist, renderer)
     65 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py in draw(self, renderer)
    826             gc = renderer.new_gc()
    827             self._set_gc_clip(gc)
--> 828             rgbaFace = self._get_rgba_face()
    829             rgbaFaceAlt = self._get_rgba_face(alt=True)
    830             edgecolor = self.get_markeredgecolor()

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py in _get_rgba_face(self, alt)
   1335     def _get_rgba_face(self, alt=False):
   1336         facecolor = self._get_markerfacecolor(alt=alt)
-> 1337         if is_string_like(facecolor) and facecolor.lower() == 'none':
   1338             rgbaFace = None
   1339         else:

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   2968             if name in self._info_axis:
   2969                 return self[name]
-> 2970             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   2971 
   2972     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'

<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x9db80b8>
```

i study the code from another case like this. if I use ax1.plot instead of ax1.plot_date, then the error information change to :

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py in to_rgba(c, alpha)
        140     try:
    --> 141         rgba = _colors_full_map.cache[c, alpha]
        142     except (KeyError, TypeError):  # Not in cache, or unhashable.

    C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __hash__(self)
        830         raise TypeError('{0!r} objects are mutable, thus they cannot be'
    --> 831                         ' hashed'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
        832 

    TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
        305                 pass
        306             else:
    --> 307                 return printer(obj)
        308             # Finally look for special method names
        309             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

    C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
        225 
        226     if 'png' in formats:
    --> 227         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
        228     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
        229         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

    C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
        117 
        118     bytes_io = BytesIO()
    --> 119     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
        120     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
        121     if fmt == 'svg':

    C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
       2190                     orientation=orientation,
       2191                     dryrun=True,
    -> 2192                     **kwargs)
       2193                 renderer = self.figure._cachedRenderer
       2194                 bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(renderer)

    C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
        543 
        544     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
    --> 545         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
        546         renderer = self.get_renderer()
        547         original_dpi = renderer.dpi

    C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in draw(self)
        462 
        463         try:
    --> 464             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
        465         finally:
        466             RendererAgg.lock.release()

    C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, 

renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     61     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     62         before(artist, renderer)
---> 63         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     64         after(artist, renderer)
     65 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   1141 
   1142             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
-> 1143                 renderer, self, dsu, self.suppressComposite)
   1144 
   1145             renderer.close_group('figure')

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, dsu, suppress_composite)
    137     if not_composite or not has_images:
    138         for zorder, a in dsu:
--> 139             a.draw(renderer)
    140     else:
    141         # Composite any adjacent images together

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     61     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     62         before(artist, renderer)
---> 63         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     64         after(artist, renderer)
     65 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2407             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
   2408 
-> 2409         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, dsu)
   2410 
   2411         renderer.close_group('axes')

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, dsu, suppress_composite)
    137     if not_composite or not has_images:
    138         for zorder, a in dsu:
--> 139             a.draw(renderer)
    140     else:
    141         # Composite any adjacent images together

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     61     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     62         before(artist, renderer)
---> 63         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     64         after(artist, renderer)
     65 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py in draw(self, renderer)
    801                 self._set_gc_clip(gc)
    802 
--> 803                 ln_color_rgba = self._get_rgba_ln_color()
    804                 gc.set_foreground(ln_color_rgba, isRGBA=True)
    805                 gc.set_alpha(ln_color_rgba[3])

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py in _get_rgba_ln_color(self, alt)
   1342 
   1343     def _get_rgba_ln_color(self, alt=False):
-> 1344         return mcolors.to_rgba(self._color, self._alpha)
   1345 
   1346     # some aliases....

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py in to_rgba(c, alpha)
    141         rgba = _colors_full_map.cache[c, alpha]
    142     except (KeyError, TypeError):  # Not in cache, or unhashable.
--> 143         rgba = _to_rgba_no_colorcycle(c, alpha)
    144         try:
    145             _colors_full_map.cache[c, alpha] = rgba

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py in _to_rgba_no_colorcycle(c, alpha)
    190     # not numpy floats.
    191     try:
--> 192         c = tuple(map(float, c))
    193     except TypeError:
    194         raise ValueError("Invalid RGBA argument: {!r}".format(orig_c))

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'k'

<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x263096fa128>
```

why this happen?

and what i really what to do is make a bar chart of cumsum size and plot price in the same image
or
if size>n(linspace maybe 50,100,200),make the whole background which in several time range in different colors. like between 2017-8-19 08:20:10 and 2017-8-19 08:30:20,size=70,then use yellow to fill this range background.and between 2017-8-20 08:20:10 and 2017-8-20 08:30:20,size=150,then use red to fill this range background.

just solve one problem is good, some idea can not figure out in one time:)

Comment: You would want to create a [mcve] of the issue, which people can copy and run to reproduce the issue. Otherwise how would one be able to provide help?

Comment: thank you for guiding,i edit the question